# Firebird embeded and EntityFramework code first: what's the correct way to set connection string and provider?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird-embedded

I have to use Firebird embeded database and Entity Framework. I have downloaded the Connector and if i use this code:

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

[...]

string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(
    new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);

FbConnectionStringBuilder fbStringBuilder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
fbStringBuilder.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;
fbStringBuilder.UserID = "SYSDBA";
fbStringBuilder.Password = "MASTERKEY";
fbStringBuilder.Dialect = 3;
fbStringBuilder.Charset = "UTF8";
fbStringBuilder.ClientLibrary = Path.Combine(exePath, "fbembed.dll");
fbStringBuilder.Database = Path.Combine(exePath, "test.fdb");


if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(exePath, "test.fdb")))
{
    FbConnection.CreateDatabase(fbStringBuilder.ToString());
}

FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(fbStringBuilder.ToString());

try
{
    fbConn.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
finally
{
    fbConn.Close();
}
```

Everything works. But when I try to use that connection string with DbContext:

```
public class FirebirdEmbededExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FirebirdEmbededExampleDbContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connString;
    }

    public DbSet<ItemA> ItemsA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemB> ItemsB { get; set; }
}
```

it fails with message:

```
Unsupported keyword: 'server type'
```

It looks like EF isn't using Firebird provider. How should I use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DbContext` should look like this:

```
public class FirebirdEmbededExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FirebirdEmbededExampleDbContext(string connString) 
      : base(new FbConnection(connString), true)
    { }

    public DbSet<ItemA> ItemsA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemB> ItemsB { get; set; }
}
```

You have to give it a clue it should be using `FirebirdClient`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for something and found these resources. Hope it helps you:

> **Using the Firebird embedded server**
>   User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=SampleDatabase.fdb;DataSource=localhost;
>   Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection
>   lifetime=15;Pooling=true; MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet
>   Size=8192;ServerType=1;
>
> *It's the key/value ServerType=1; that tells the driver it's in*
>   *embedded mode.*

And from the Firebird website:
http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebird_v2.1.4.InstallationGuide.pdf from embeded package:

> Client access can be only via the local (XNET) protocol, i.e. NOT a TCP/IP local loopback connection string that includes the server name “localhost” or the IP address 127.0.0.1. The embedded server supports only the local connect to an absolute database file path without a server name.

so this `DataSource=localhost` is not supported (when I run that code i get the same error with `Unsupported keyword: 'datasource'`)

But there is one more thing. The FAQ say (http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-net-provider-faq/#1):

> 1. What versions of the MS.NET Framework are supported?
>
> .NET 1.0, .NET 1.1, .NET 2.0 and the .NET Compact Framework 2.0

but in the download section says (http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/):

> October 5, 2013 - NETProvider-3.2.0.0.msi - 815 KB - FirebirdClient, Windows installer
>
> October 5, 2013 - NETProvider-3.2.0.0-NET40.7z - 322 KB - FirebirdClient - .NET 4.0
>
> October 5, 2013 - NETProvider-3.2.0.0-NET45.7z - 349 KB - FirebirdClient - .NET 4.5

So connector is for NET 4.0/4.5 but embeded says it supports only NET 2.0 ? I'm bit confused...