# MVC 4 Database First project: Setting DBContext for the life of the controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not sure that the title of my thread really explains what I am trying to do, so I will better explain it here.  I am new to MVC and I have a project that I am working on.  I am connecting to a Firebird database and, as of right now, I am setting up the connection string and the connection itself within the Index() of one of the controllers.  This is fine in that the connection is created and it returns my list to the View as it should.  I can go back into my View and I can select another database and it will connect to the new database and display the results as normal.  I realize that the better way to do this is to create a DAL class, I am sure, but for now, bear with me.

All this works wonderfully.  Where I hit a snag (as you might imagine) is when I try to Edit, Save, or Delete anything.  Obviously, those methods are looking at the dbContext and nothing has changed with the DBContext.  The DBContext is not necessarily "updated" by my connection code.  I can create the connection when I want to, but I cannot "set" it for the life of the controller, as it were.

Basically, I am just asking for some advice.  I have been scouring StackOverflow and I think I have found some information that might help me, but it is a little over my head still.  Just trying to get a grasp on using the DBcontext to dynamically change my connection string for the entire controller, not just the Index().

Thanks in advance.

EDITED TO SHOW CONTEXT CODE

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{

    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    public Entities(string providerString)
        : base(new FbConnection(providerString), true)
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = providerString;
    }
```

This gives an error upon the return View(); of the Index.

UPDATED CONTROLLER CODE:

```
            FbConnectionStringBuilder fbBuilder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                DataSource = dbsource,
                Database = dbdir,
                UserID = dbuser,
                Password = dbpwd,
                Dialect = 3,
                PacketSize = 8192
            };

            // Build the FbConnection connection string.
            FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(fbBuilder.ToString());

            db = new Entities(fbConn.ToString());
```

UPDATED DBCONTEXT:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{

    public Entities(string fbConn)
        : base(new FbConnection(fbConn), true)
    {
    }
```

However, this now produces the error:

An invalid connection string argument has been supplied or a required connection string argument has not been supplied.

But this doesn't make sense, because if I use this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, then I can connect, so I know it is getting a good string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding some workarounds. Added code below:

Model.context.cs:

```
    public MyDatabaseContext()
        : base("name=MyDatabaseContextEntities")
    {
    }

    public MyDatabaseContext(string connectionString)
        : base("name=MyDatabaseContextEntities")
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public static string temporaryConnectionString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    FbConnectionStringBuilder fbBuilder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
          //code to build your connection
    };

    //connectionString defined as a public variable
    connectionString = fbBuilder.ToString();

    //store to session variable in your DAL
    context.DataConnection.DAL.CurrentConnection = connectionString;
    temporaryConnectionString = connectionString;
    context = new MyDatabaseContext(connectionString);

    return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**Easiest**

Add a property to the controller to hold your `DbContext`, then add a parameterless ctor that will populate is (effectively giving it a lifespan of that of the controller). e.g.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    public MyController()
    {
        this.context = new DbContext();
    }

    // rest of actions reference `context.<whatever>`
}
```

**More Involved**

Introduce Inversion of Control (IoC) in to the equation with some form of Dependency Injector (DI). Then, let the resolver place the context in the controller when it's instantiated. The new controller signature then looks like:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    public MyController(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // rest of actions reference `context.<whatever>`
}
```

*Note: The parameterless ctor went away, but your DependencyResolver will automatically insert the correct instance in when the controller's created.*

From there, you need to declare which instance in the DI's configuration. Using ninject as an example, something like:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContexT>().To<MyDbContext>()
    // here's where scope comes in to play:
    // for ninject: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes
    //.InTransientScope();
    //.InSingletonScope();
    //.InThreadScope();
    //.InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight!  I will give this a shot and rate your answer after I get it working.

Comment: Hm, that didn't quite solve it.  Maybe I can give you more information about the bigger problem at hand and you can offer a suggestion to get the above code working.  I am using Database first and I have a web.config with a site's database hard-coded in (not for a particular purpose, but I am trying to avoid using the web.config at all).  So, when I go to connect to that database, it connects just fine (using my connection code) and then when I edit, save, delete, etc. it will do so, but only to the database in the web.config.

Comment: So, if I connect to another database, and go to edit, save, delete, etc. it will error out because it is trying to do these functions on another database, but it is looking at the web.config for its connection.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3280382: Does the name of your connection string match the name of the context? Or does your context supply the `nameOrConnectionString` parameter to the base `DbContext`? it's going to use whatever connection string was provided (albeit the matching name, or the one supplied in the ctor).

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I had "name=Entities" in the   base parameter of my context.  Let me show you how it looks now that you mentioned the base parameter:public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        
        public Entities()
            : base("name=Entities")
        {
        }
        
        public Entities(string providerString)
            : base(new FbConnection(providerString), true)
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = providerString;
        }`

Comment: Going to try to better format the above for you.  But the above gives me an error when it passes the FbBuilder connection string:  "A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly."

Comment: Is your connection named "Entities"? Also, which constructor is your application using--the parameterless one or the one that provides `providerString`?

Comment: I edited my original post so the code looked more streamlined.  Sorry - new to posting on StackOverflow. Connection string is named "Entities", providerString parameter is what is being passed from the code to the dbcontext.  Here is how I am passing the connection:  
                
                providerString = fbBuilder.ToString();

                db = new Entities(providerString);

Comment: so then what is the `FbConnection`?

Comment: That is what I added (from reading comments about similar topics from StackOverflow) to the base of the dbcontext.  Without specifying that it was an FbConnection, I was getting "keyword not supported 'dialect'".  So, I added FbConnection and I don't get that error anymore, but I get the error I listed above.  I have been looking at it for so long now that I am sort of turned around now.

Comment: Ahh, `FbConnection` is your Firebird SQL connection wrapper--that makes sense. So given that, try removing the `this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` assignment and just pass the base class (`DbContext`) the populated `FbConnection`.

Comment: I have updated my Controller/DBcontext in my main question.  Does it look like you're suggesting?

Comment: Something more like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19265228/298053). keep the `base(new FbContext(...))` but remove the `this.Database.Connection.connectionString` assignment in the ctor.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking around, Brad.  I updated by question above.  Getting an invalid connection string error now.

Comment: @user3280382: what version of EF are you using? because I found a limitation with using the firebirdSQl EF library & version 6.

Comment: System.Data.Entity reports version 4.0.0.

Comment: I got it working with some workarounds.  Thank you for all of your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3280382: Don't forget to post the solution (as an answer) for anyone else that may be trying to get the two to work together. ;-) [Then of course accept the answer].